# How does the (int) case works?

Tags: java, casting

I'd been searching for a solution how to convert one data type to another( ex: double to int, or long to int & etc). I found something like intValue() which did not really help me and then I found this construction :

```
int result= (int) /double value here/;
```

I could not find anything about this solution and how it really works and if it works for all primitive data types. Also, I would really appreciate it if you could explain the case with intValue(). I suppose it doesn't work with primitive data types but my IDE does not recognise this method in any case.
If my question is answered in any tutorials or articles feel free to redirect me.

Thank you in advance!
Peace and Love!!!

Comment: It's Java! I forgot to write that in tags and my question. Sorry about that!

Comment: `"I've never heard of intValue"` - It is an instance method on `java.lang.Integer`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are really asking.  Are you asking what happens when a `double` is cast to an `int`?

Comment: int result = (int)3.14; will work.  Your code as given does not use comments properly (inline comments are double-slash, and you cannot inline-comment before the semicolon). What is your error exactly? And, yes (int) casting works on all primitives. Characters turn to their ascii code and booleans turn to 0/1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Casting like this works for any compatible primitive types, and does the appropriate rounding/truncation.  This is the normal way to convert between primitive types.

The precise rules of how they work are defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).